# Alert after form radio has been selected

Tags: forms, ajax, routes

I am trying to use drupal ajax to test if an email address from the form it is in my database. For that i have altered the form and added the following line to the element:

```
   $form['field_radio']['#ajax'] = array
    (
       'callback' => '_get_member',
       'progress' => array('type' => 'throbber', 'message' => '')
    );
```

and the callback function:

```
function _get_member($form, $form_state){

     $sid = $form_state['values']['details']['sid'];
    $commands[] = ajax_command_alert("Hello World");    

    return array(
    'type' => 'ajax',
    'commands' => $commands
  ); 
}
```

As you can see from the callback i just want to return an alert message but it does not work. The callback is called because i have tested using watchdog but the alert popup never fires. Why ?

Answer (score 0):

'wrapper' is a required key for `#ajax` on form elements, you're probably just missing that. From [the docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7#ajax)

> This property is required for using AJAX requests in on a form element

If you add the wrapper it should work:

```
$form['field_radio']['#ajax'] = array (
   'callback' => '_get_member',
   'progress' => array('type' => 'throbber', 'message' => ''),
   'wrapper' => 'some-element-id'
);
```

Comment: i have added the wrapper key but still the alert is not fired! Is there a way to grab variables from the result with javascript ?

Comment: In the ajax response i found the text : "command":"alert", "text":"Based on your email, you are not a Member yet!"